# another way for adding a title to a uinavbar programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel, uinavigationbar

I am trying to add a title to my nav bar which I have added programmatically. I know i can create a label and add it as a subview, but then I need to add tons of configurations for it to be placed correctly like in a typical nav bar title. Is there any other way to do that than this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

//Adding navBar programmatically 
CGFloat width = self.view.frame.size.width;
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,width,52)];
navBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

//Adding title programmatically 
UILabel *lblTitle  = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,80,30)];
lblTitle.text = @"Title";
[navBar addSubview: lblTitle];

[self.view addSubview:navBar];

}
```

And if not (sorry for another question, just think it relates) how do I set up my lblTitle to look like a normal nav bar title that you will find in most of the apps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are adding the navigation bar by programmatically means, use this

```
 (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"yourTitle";
}
```

You can also use

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"yourTitle";
```

Comment: Doesnt work....:( I also forgot to mention that a UITabBarController is pushing this view controller. Not sure it matters.

Comment: Thats ok everyone - I ended up adding a navcontroller in which case all your suggestions work. I am not sure why it was so difficult, but ohh well...thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Your Title";
```

Comment: Doesnt work....:( I also forgot to mention that a UITabBarController is pushing this view controller. Not sure it matters.

Answer (score 3):

The best answer to your question is just to use a `UINavigationController` to get its navigation bar for free, but if for some reason you can’t do that, you’ll need to use a custom `UILabel` and play with its properties until you match the style of the built-in one.

Comment: Doesnt work....:( I also forgot to mention that a UITabBarController is pushing this view controller. Not sure it matters.

Answer (score 0):

If a simple UILabel does not satisfy you, then yes, you need tons of configuration or you can do that in Interface Builder to polish your view. Instead of adding it as a subview, I suggest that you set it as `navigationItem.titleView` in your `-(void)viewDidLoad`.